# Yii2 CORS filters allow only specific origin domains fails

Tags: php, yii2, cors

I have the following in my behaviors

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ],
        'except' => ['login', 'check-token-validity', 'test-accounts'],
    ];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // 'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,

            'Origin' => static::allowedDomains(),

            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'PUT'],

            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['Access_status_code'],
        ],
    ];
    $behaviors['verbs'] = [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'delete' => ['POST', 'OPTIONS'],
        ],
    ];
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    //access
    return $behaviors;
}


    public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
        'http://test1.example.com',
        'http://test2.example.com',
    ];
}
```

As from the above, I have set origin as the above static domains but when I checked on my ajax request response I found out that the response header origin is set as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Also, I haven't been able to restrict access methods despite setting `Access-Control-Request-Method`

What else do I need to add for this to work?

Comment: Does the response still have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if you send a *request* with `Origin: http://not.on.the.white.list/`?

Comment: Yes the respose still has Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * even when the origin is not on the whitelisted domain

Comment: How do you send ajax?